# How would I direct all traffic that hasn't logged in to django allauth login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Want to direct all un-logged in traffic to the login page. How would I go about doing this? I don't want visitors to be able to see the site at all if they are not logged in. As well, the allauth signup page should not be able to be accessed either. Users will be pre-registered for the site. I'm fairly new to django and would not want to abandon allauth as I have it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py file import following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

Then all you have to do is to add this decorator before the views in your urlpatterns. Something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', login_required(views.index), name='home'),
    url(r'^update-profile/$', login_required(views.update_profile), name="update_profile"),
]
```

As long as you have defined registration model and have login.html page setup, this should direct all the traffic to login page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this in your views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


 def index(request):
   if request.user.is_authenticated():
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
   else:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```